# Read bytes from string as floats

Tags: python, string, byte

I've got a python webserver where small binary files are POST:ed. The posted data is represented as strings. I want to examine the contents of these strings. But to do that, I need to convert each 4 bytes to floats (little endian). How do you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `struct` is best for unpacking collection of "scalar" binary values, when you what you have is a sequence of 4-byte binary floats in a string one after the other, the [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module is ideal.  Specifically, it's as simple as:

```
import array
thefloats = array.array('f', thestring)
```

If only part of `thestring` contains the sequence of 4-byte binary floats, you can build the array from that part by using the appropriate slice of the string instead of the entire string. The `array` instance offers most of the functionality of `list` (plus handy methods to convert to/from strings of bytes and swap between little-endian and big-endian forms if needed), but it's less flexible (only floats can be in the array) and enormously more compact (can take up 3-4 times less memory than a list with the same items).

Comment: Wow, this was very easy and powerful.

Comment: @quano, glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 7):

You use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack_from("f", "\43\a3\12\32")
(8.6198787687447256e-33,)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/) module might also be a handy way to do this. It should be easy to adapt [this example](http://construct.wikispaces.com/tut-basics) to your needs:

```
# [U]nsigned, [L]ittle endian, 16 bit wide integer (parsing)
>>> ULInt16("foo").parse("\x01\x02")
513
```